# Check for letter after a substring

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I'm trying to find a way to check whether or not an alpha-numeric character follows a portion of a string. For example, if the sub-string is: `sub`, and the text is: `substrings are cool`, it should return `True` and if the text is: `sub dafdgnjgf` it should return `False`.

Comment: would you please clarify what you really want to do?

Comment: Should `xyz subA sub B` return `True` or `False`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for *any* valid letter after a given sub-string, you can first find the position of that sub-string inside the string with `str.find`, then check if the index after the sub-string matches `ascii_letters` from `string`:

```
from string import ascii_letters

sub = 'sub'
s = 'substrings are cool'
```

Now, your check can look like this, index the string after at the position `str.find(sub) + len(sub)` i.e the position after the sub-string:

```
if s[s.find(sub) + len(sub)] in ascii_letters:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

This prints `True` if `sub` is followed by a letter, if not:

```
s = 'sub dafdgnjgf'
```

it prints `False`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) with the substring as a lookbehind, matching a character:

```
>>> p = re.compile(r"(?<=sub)([a-zA-Z])")
>>> p.search("substrings are cool")
<_sre.SRE_Match at 0x7f3a50dbc300>
>>> p.search("substrings are cool").group()
's'
>>> p.search("sub dafdgnjgf")
None
```